# sunflower project can't be compiled because LocationAwareException

Tags: android

[sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower) is by Google's documentation a demo project for android's new features. It has complicated registration requirement to be compiled. I have done that. Even though it can't be compiled. but i get error at the bottom of this message.
How to proceed? Is this project valid, even though some files are updated lately, but most many years ago? Maybe not, because I have downloaded last version from github and use last version of android studio

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 28, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-170-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: idea.plugin.protoeditor (212.5080.8), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), net.sjrx.intellij.plugins.systemdunitfiles (0.3.9), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46)
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Error
`org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file /git/sunflower/app/build.gradle.kts line: 17 An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.2'] at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:207) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:146) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$200(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$add$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:119) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142) at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:220) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:391) at Program.execute(Unknown Source) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:523) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:218) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:121) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:48) at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:35) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62) at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:413) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394) at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46) at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27) at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35) at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394) at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68) at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:782) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:156) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:195) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:369) at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33) at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:49) at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:65) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68) at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40) at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209) at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84) at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:130) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:130) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:278) at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:140) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31) at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116) at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40) at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65) at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88) at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75) at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.2'] at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:222) at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)`

I tried to compile and try demo.